# Find matching pairs in events table

Tags: sql

I have a `device_events` table in which I get signals from various devices. These events could be `online` `offline` events for a device. Basically I want all the offline and online events for a device to be paired. We can assume that the online event will always be preceded by an offline event.

The table will look something like this:

| trigger | device_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Online | 1 | 2022-01-23 17:39:12.986 |
| Offline | 1 | 2022-01-23 17:38:12.986 |
| Online | 1 | 2022-01-22 16:39:12.986 |
| Offline | 1 | 2022-01-22 16:38:12.986 |
| Online | 2 | 2022-01-21 14:39:12.986 |
| Offline | 2 | 2022-01-21 14:38:12.986 |
| Offline | 3 | 2022-01-20 14:38:12.986 |

I want the following output:

| device_id | device_offline | device_online |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 17:38:12.986 | 2022-01-23 17:39:12.986 |
| 1 | 2022-01-22 16:38:12.986 | 2022-01-22 16:39:12.986 |
| 2 | 2022-01-21 14:38:12.986 | 2022-01-21 14:39:12.986 |
| 3 | 2022-01-20 14:38:12.986 | [NULL] |

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you have also a autoincremt field in the table

Comment: Yes. There is a `id` field which will be auto incremented.

Comment: Can we assume a) the first event for a device is always offline b) event always go in sequence of offline, online, offline, online etc? If so, just query for the offline events and use a LEAD window function to get the corresponding online event

Comment: @NickW Yes. That's a fair assumption to make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a self `left join`:

```
select d.device_id, d.created_at, d1.created_at from device_events d 
left join device_events d1 on d1.device_id = d.device_id and d1.trigger = 'Online' 
    and d1.created_at = (select min(d3.created_at) from device_events d3 where d3.trigger = 'Online' 
        and d3.device_id = d.device_id and d3.created_at >= d.created_at) 
where d.trigger = 'Offline'
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UwXhshXE)

Answer (score 0):

Using a correlated query:

```
select device_id, created_at Device_Offline,
  (
    select created_at from t t2 
    where t2.device_id = t.device_id and t2.created_at > t.created_at
    order by t2.created_at
    limit 1
  ) device_online
from t
where trigger = 'Offline'
order by device_id, Device_Offline desc;
```

Example [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qiULGzzI)